# How to skip login page when using Windows identity in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I have an MVC client app authenticated by IdentityServer4 using Windows external identity (not Azure Ad). It is working fine except that each time I run the app, the IdentityServer4 login page will display and I need to click on the "Windows" button to continue. My guess is, there must be a way that I can bypass these unnecessary steps, taking "Windows" as default, and login "silently". Can that be done? If so, how?

Comment: What does the "Windows" button do? Can not you call the same code in the login page GET action?

Comment: Well, I guess I could always write my own code to do that, but I just feel that there should be some "standard", or preferred ways to achieve that.

Comment: IdentityServer4 is just an OIDC implementation, it doesn't care about how users ultimately get authenticated so there's no such thing as "standard" really, only the cobbling together of other libraries.